# How to deploy spring boot jar file to EC2 using jenkins?

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, jenkins, continuous-deployment

i am trying to deploy the spring boot app to AWS EC2 instances. i have seen lot of blog and tutorial explained deployment process completely which is understandable. i am struggling how to do continuous deployment or delivery in jenkins which main feature where spring boot app name or jar file name changes that time.

my pipeline

```
  pipeline {
    agent any

    tools{
       maven 'localmaven' 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
               sh 'mvn clean package' 
            }
            post {
               success {
                    echo 'Now Archiving...'
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.jar'
                   }
              } 
          }


    stage('Deliver') {
        steps {
             sh 'scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey target/*.jar ubuntu@00.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu'
             sh "sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey ubuntu@00.00.00.00 '/home/ubuntu/start.sh'"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Server start and stop and restart are handled in shell script.

my start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/aws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > /home/ubuntu/log.txt 2>&1 &
echo $! > /home/ubuntu/pid.file
```

This start my server perfectly and works fine..

here my doubt is currently in start.sh i am using same jar file name so it works fine but in production with version change jar file name also change how to handle that situation. 
Help me to know about that process. Where i can get that complete idea and everything 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must say you should maintain you artifact’s version as a standard process for non-prod and prod deployment. Usually in non-prod environment you can plan for **SNAPSHOT** version and in production you should go for **RELEASE** version which can be generated using `mvn release prepare release perform` using [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/). It will bump up  your pom version for next subsequent releases. You can store your artifact to AWS S3 or Artifactory or Nexus  (for high availability ) like the ubuntu machine that you are referring here.

Now I would suggest you should add one more stage named like **stage('Release')** where you should use using maven-release-plugin to release the version and store it to a separate path like

> ubuntu@00.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu/RELEASE/${version}

and as per you stage('Build')  should copy to another path like

> ubuntu@00.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu/SNAPSHOT/${version}

You can execute stage '**Release**' and '**Prod-Deliver**' based on conditional input parameter of your Jenkins pipeline.
Here would be a possible solution for a smooth CICD in your case.

```
   pipeline {
    agent any

    tools{
       maven 'localmaven' 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
               sh 'mvn clean install' 
            }
            post {
               success {
                    echo 'Now Archiving...'
                   }
              } 
          }

        stage('Release') { 
            steps {
               sh 'elease:prepare release:perform' 
            }
            post {
               success {
                    ////
                   }
              } 
          }

      stage('NonProd-Deliver') {
          steps {
               /*
               You can extract the version from pom.xml,replace you project location in jenkins workspace in the below command
               */
               sh 'version=$(echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:version/text()' | xmllint --shell ${YOUR_PROJECT_LOCATION}/pom.xml | grep -v /)'
               sh 'scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey target/*.jar ubuntu@00.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu/SNAPSHOT/${version}'
               sh "sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey ubuntu@00.00.00.00 '/home/ubuntu/start.sh nonprod $version'"
          }
      }

       stage('Prod-Deliver') {
        steps {
              /*
               For production release you should pass the version as a parameter to your jenkins pipeline which is going to be in production
               */
             sh 'scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey target/*.jar ubuntu@00.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu/RELEASE/${version} '
             sh "sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey ubuntu@00.00.00.00 '/home/ubuntu/start.sh prod ${version}'"
        }
    }

}
}
```

You have to add the condtion in your script file as well like below

```
#!/bin/bash
release_type=$1
version=$2
if [[ ${release_type} == "prod" ]]; then
  # non snapshot release to production env
  nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/RELEASE/${version}/aws-0.0.1.jar > /home/ubuntu/log.txt 2>&1 & 
else
  # snapshot release to non production env
  nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/SNAPSHOT/${version}/aws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > /home/ubuntu/log.txt 2>&1 &
fi
echo $! > /home/ubuntu/pid.file
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say keep the name of the final artifact as a constant name using the `build.finalName` and have a provision to keep the build version somewhere inside the build.

As I see that you use spring boot, You can save version information part of the build by using `build-info` goal of `spring-boot-maven-plugin` as shown below.

```
  <build>
    <finalName>your-artifact-name</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

and access the maven build information via the actuator endpoint `http://localhost:8080/actuator/info`.

Or, You can get the version information saved in `classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties` by looking into the jar file by using the following command.

```
$> unzip -qc your-artifact-name.jar META-INF/build-info.properties
#Properties
#Fri May 04 17:43:06 IST 2018
build.time=2018-05-04T12\:13\:06.225Z
build.artifact=your-artifact-name
build.group=com.example
build.name=your-artifact-name
build.version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
```

This way the build version is not changed even when there was an accidental renaming of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the filename as an argument to the shell script, i.e. modify the shell script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/$1 > /home/ubuntu/log.txt 2>&1 &
echo $! > /home/ubuntu/pid.file
```

and then you would need to determine the correct filename to use, based on the build version, and pass that as an argument to the script in the Deliver stage.

Comment: How to pass that as a n argument?

Comment: @Robin Green - $1 means first available file name from current working directory right.

Comment: @Pranavadurai no, it means first argument of the script when the script is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rename the file when you do an scp

```
scp filename username@remote.host.net.:filenewname
```

In your case something like this

```
sh 'scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey target/*.jar ubuntu@00.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu:aws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

The above code takes whatever build version has been created by jenkins and at the time of copying it and renames it to "aws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", so you dont have to modify your start.sh

P.S generally when you deploy your final build(JAR) ensure that only the jar name is added as the description to the filename and not "-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

Hope it helps :)

Comment: by this method we are hard coding that this the file name always right. is there any way to predict the file name no hard code or anything

Comment: @ion We are hard coding the final name of the file, which is to be be deployed into the server(based on your question) ....I'm not sure I understand what you fully want ....Why do you want to predict the name of a file which you build using maven ?? The above code (target/*.jar) takes whatever(filename) JAR is built in target folder and renames it...