# Building and deploying Spring Boot to EC2

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jenkins

Looking to build and deploy my spring-boot application here: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API

I can't seem seem to find a clear explination thus far? Any clear cut examples?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what your issue is. If you have packaged your app in a self contained jar, you can just start the app/jar on the server. What are your exact issues/problems?

Comment: It’s not so much a problem, just don’t know how to build a spring boot app, then deploy that built jar to an EC2. Two separate stages in my pipeline essentially.

Comment: OK. Given a pipeline, such as Jenkins, you would need to 'scp' the jar to the correct location on the EC2 instance, and then issue a remote command to execute a start script. I think this has been asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186447/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-jar-file-to-ec2-using-jenkins